# WebBrowser Internet Explorer version configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

This is the simple code that i want to run, but the webbrowser will not display it.
I have tested on IE on my machine and it works correctly. I know .NET uses IE 7, i have gone into the registry and set it up change to IE 11, but the site is still not visible. Would anyone have an idea of how to get this to work. Can visual studio be changed to use IE 11. 
I am not using a Proxy.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/");
    }
```

Comment: Please note that "visual studio" is not synonymous with "C#" or ".NET". The `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions relating to the IDE, not code merely written in it.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, you have to tell the `WebBrowser` object to properly use it as explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/f4dc3550-f213-41ff-a17d-95c917bed027/webbrowser-control-for-setting-proxy?forum=winforms).

Comment: Run a web search for "webbrowser ajax call", it might help